# Google Sheets Date Stamp Script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I hope you can help me please
I am using this cool script I found online which is supposed to automatically add the current date into Column A when data is entered into the row for the rest of the columns. I am using Zapier to have new rows automatically created when said data is received.
Now the problem is, it's not doing this when Zapier adds the new row. However it does it if I manually go and put data into Column B for example.
Can anyone have a look for me please and see what is wrong/missing:

```
/**
* Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
*/

//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 2;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,-1];

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1,2];
  var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('dd/mm/yy');
      }
  }
```

Comment: `onEdit` triggers only fire when the sheet is edited by a user, not automatically by another program.

Comment: Oh I see...thanks for that. I'm assuming if I run the script manually it might apply the function for me then